# Stiffness of a suspension

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I think It is a trivial question from the point of view of engineering. But I am curious. Suppose you have to make a suspension. A less stiff spring will not do the job. It would just slide over. An infinite stiff spring will not do the job either. It would act as a rigid part of the body and will have nothing to do with absorbing shock. So how can one calculate the intermediate stiffness(spring constant) to make a suspension?

Comment: It essentially depends upon your definition of "infinite" and "less stiff"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends exactly what your suspension is designed to do. Often you want your system to return to close to the equilibrium position as fast as possible, but without undergoing any futher oscillation. This is achieved by "critical damping". In the usual harmonic oscillator, if you write the equation of motion as
$$ a \ddot{x} + b\dot{x} +cx = 0,$$
where $b$ is the "damping term".
Critical damping is achieved when $b^2 = 4ac$, when there is only one repeated root of the auxiliary equation.

However it is possible to have slightly weaker damping in order to return to the equilibrium position sooner, at the expense of some overshoot by some defined maximum amount. In which case you have to work through the maths to see what constraint this puts on $a,b,c$.